# JAR vs WAR file specification

Tags: java, jar, war

I noticed that WAR files are supposed to have `classes/` and `lib/` directories for containing their classfile root and dependencies, respectively.

I also noticed that it is not common practice for JARs to contain such a `lib/` directory and to contain their own dependencies.

So now I'm wondering why JARs shouldn't/usually-don't contain their own dependencies, but WAR files are *expected* to. Unless I'm missing something, both require their dependencies to be on the classpath at runtime (JARs won't run if they're missing dependencies, just like WARs won't run). So to me, all the arguments for putting dependencies in a WAR file also apply to a JAR.

What am I not "getting" here?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a conceptual point of view:
A `jar` typically represents a single library which can be used and may or may not have dependencies.
But the idea is that a specific functionality can be provided as a library in a `jar`.

A `war` is an application by itself and as such it should include all the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

They are containers with different purposes.

- `Jar` is intended for `Java` class files and resources and can be a library or a directly runnable application.
- `War` is a container to package *complete* **Web** applications including all dependencies (such as Jar files and other web resources).

The question boils down to, why can't a `jar` include other `jar`s. This I would take as a design decision taken to allow maximum flexibility in interchanging dependencies.

Comment: So what about an executable jar, like a Swing app?

Comment: @AdamTannon, a `Jar` file can be directly executable while a `War` cannot

Answer (score 0):

WAR files (mainly WEB applications) are uncompressed, and all JAR files inside the lib folder will be in the classpath of your web application while running.

JAR files might also contain jar files, but will not be found and loaded by the default class loader.

There are special class loaders that do load jar files inside jar files, but not standard.

Answer (score 0):

Because unless you use a custom classloader that can load classes from nested jars (like [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php)), you can't load classes from nested jars. Servlet and app containers will add jars contained inside war/ear files to their application's classpath.