# Nested apps within a WAR file in Geronimo

Tags: java, servlets, web, geronimo

I am not an experienced web developer but lately I have been involved in the development of some web applications (Java Servlets + JavaScript + HTML5). With experience in standalone projects this question makes sense to me but I understand it can be absurd for an expert web developer:

I would like to develop some common applications and integrate them into bigger projects.
For example, I would like to develop an users manager web app which could be used by different products. So I could encapsulate it into a WAR file and include it in a project or another.

[image]

As it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723888/jar-vs-war-file-specification/9723953#9723953), I understand a WAR package is not a JAR containing libs but a package to deploy a complete application.

My goal is to reuse the same code without having to include all "UsersManager" files one by one into App1 and App2 packages. Currently, I think the best solution is to publish "UsersManager" and call it from App1 or App2. Nevertheless, if "UsersManager" and "App1", for example, are published at different contexts they don't share session variables. If "UsersManager" includes a Login service and it creates some session data these session variables should be accesible from "App1".

[image]

What should I try?

- Make a redirect call from App1/App2 to UsersManager?
- Forget about sharing sessions?
- What is the right solution to this kind of problems?

Comment: I won't say sharing session but instead use a Single Sign-On solution for all your common applications, so the user logs in when trying to access to one of the application and their credentials are shared among all the applications. Refer to [Which SSO Framework to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/173704/1065197)

Comment: Login service is just an example, what if I want to integrate other services such as calendar module?

Comment: Having a single login for your app, you can get the data for the same user among different applications.

Comment: You are right: http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDEV/single-sign-on.html

Comment: I know this since in my workplace we use SSO and all the applications are *linked* by having the same user accessing through different applications hosted in different physical/virtual servers.

Answer (score 0):

Since Geronimo will use a Cookie to store the client session anyway (at least with my configuration),

[image: Chrome cookies explorer]

all the web applications will require the client to accept Cookies.

On the other hand, at my company we have already a centralized session manager. I will use an additional cookie to store the session id provided by that system so that I have already a simple SSO mechanism.